# twitter4j - How to configure?

Tags: java, twitter, properties, oauth, twitter4j

I am trying to write a simple twitter client using [twitter4j](http://twitter4j.org), but I can't seem to get past the first step - configuring the parameters. There is a [configuration page](http://twitter4j.org/en/configuration.html) on the site that says I need to have a `twitter.properties` file at root with following contents:

```
debug=true
oauth.consumerKey=*********************
oauth.consumerSecret=******************************************
oauth.accessToken=**************************************************
oauth.accessTokenSecret=******************************************
```

What I am unable to figure out is what should go in place of the asterisks, and how do I obtain those values? Please help.

PS: This is my first time with OAuth and twitter4j, so please be gentle!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Login to https://dev.twitter.com  through your Twitter credentials.

And at homepage Click on [Create an app](https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new) and fill all the details .
You will get all the required key/secret.